# Hilbert space the trace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I need help from someone to solve this problem.

> Given a bounded sequence $(\lambda_n)$ in $\mathbb С$ define an operator $S$ in $B(\ell_2)$ by $S(x_1) = 0$ and 
>   $S(x_n) =  \lambda_n x_{n-1}$ , $n > 1$, for $x = (x_n) \in \ell_2$.
>   Find the polar decomposition of $S$, and characterize those sequences $\{\lambda_n\}$ in $\ell_\infty$ for which $S$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\lambda_n=|\lambda_n|e^{i\theta_n}$ and $S=UP$, where $(Px)(n)=|\lambda_n| x(n)$, and $U(x)(n)=e^{i\theta_n}x(n-1)$ if $n\geqslant 1$ and $0$ if $n=0$. Then $P$ is non-negative definite, $U$ is unitary.

Show that $S$ is compact if and only if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\lambda_n=0$. It's done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135425/compact-operators?rq=1).

Comment: is that the only thing we have to do i relly missed some thing

Comment: i mean we it is not necessary  to check the compactness

Comment: Why? If I read well, it's asked, isn't it?

Comment: i mean could u prove the compactness

Comment: Well, I'm still waiting for your attempt.

Comment: well i have a test of another subject i just go through your link and i will see u on friday with my attempt. Thanks buddy

Comment: still i m stuck with this problem can you give me some hints on the compsct part and how could it be characterized with l infinity

Comment: The characterization of these sequence is convergent sequences to $0$. Where are you stuck in the proof given in the link?

Comment: i felt defficulty with conjugate of ball but i find the consequences on it thank you very much.