# $Tx=(\lambda_kx_k)_{k=1}^\infty$. For what $(\lambda_k)$ is the operator $T$: (a) well defined? (b) bounded? (c) compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Came across this exercise in a book I'm reading. The full exercise is as such:

> For a sequence of real numbers $(\lambda_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, define a linear operator $T:l_2\rightarrow l_2$ by $Tx=(\lambda_kx_k)_{k=1}^\infty$. For what multiplier sequences $(\lambda_k)$ is the operator $T$: (a) well defined? (b) bounded? (c) compact?

Here, $l_2$ is the space of all square-summable sequences, such that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k^2<\infty$, then $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in l_2$ and $||x||=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k^2}$.

I'm not sure what is meant here by "well defined", my best guess is that it means to ask "when does the application of $T$ actually result in a sequence of the space $l_2$". Am I correct?

About boundedness, I noticed that if the sequence $(\lambda_k)$ is unbounded, then $T$ is also unbounded. This is easy to see: since $(\lambda_k)$ is unbounded, there exists a subsequence $(\lambda_{k_n})$, such that $\lambda_{k_n}>n$. But then for the sequence $x=(x_k)\in l_2$, $x_k=\frac{1}{k}$, we see that $||Tx||=||\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_kx_k||<\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1}=\infty$. And so, $Tx\not\in l_2$. Similarly, we can show that when the sequence $(\lambda_k)$ is bounded, so is $T$.

I have no idea what to do about compactness. I know that an operator is compact if and only if it maps the open unit ball to a precompact (such that its closure is compact) set. I don't see how that helps.

If anyone has any ideas about well definedness and compactness, please share them. Also please check my ideas about boundedness. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question c? [Compact multiplication operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135425/compact-multiplication-operators) (and for a, same answer as b).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, it does answer (c). Do you mean that the answer for (a) is the same as the answer for (b), as in "well defined" is the same as "bounded"?

Comment: Indeed, as a [corollary of the uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Corollaries).