# How to show that a sequence in $l^{2}$ has a convergent subseqence after the action of an operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

> **Problem:** Let $l^{2}=\{(x_{1},x_{2},...)| x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n,(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...)<\infty\}$, 
>   $\|x\|=(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.   Given
>   $\lambda_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$($n=1,2,3...$), $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow
> \infty} \lambda_{n}=0$.
>
> Define $A:l^{2}\rightarrow l^{2}$ as
>   follows: For $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...)\in l^{2}$,
>   $Ax=(\lambda_{1}x_{1},\lambda_{2}x_{2},...)$.
>
> Show that for a bounded sequence:$\{x^{(j)}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ in
>   $l^{2}$, $\{Ax^{(j)}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ has a subsequence which
>   converges in $l^{2}$.

I am new in fuctional analysis and I have no idea how to handle this problem. I am grateful to any help! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have tried this problem by myself but failed. I know that $A$ is called a compact operator. But hardly do I know any properties of it. Maybe you can tell me what properties we need to prove this and how to prove those. I really really appreciate any help! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several facts that you should use:
1) If the image of an operator is finite-dimensioned, then this operator is compact.
2) If a sequence of compact operators converges in operator norm, then the limit is also a compact operator.

Hence in your case you study a sequence of operators $A_k$ such that

$A_k(x) = (\lambda_1x_1,\dots,\lambda_kx_k,0,0,\dots)$. Apparently, $A_k$ is compact  because the dimension of the image is at most $k$.

Then we need to prove that $\|A-A_k\|\to 0$. Take an arbitrary $x\in\ell_2$ with $\|x\|=1$. We write $\|(A-A_k)(x)\| \le \sup_{r>k} |\lambda_r|\cdot \|x\|_{\ell_2}$ (it's easy to see why it's true). This allows to say that $\| A-A_k  \| \le \sup_{r>k} |\lambda_r|$.  Then again, $\sup_{r>k} |\lambda_r|\to 0 $ as $k\to\infty$ because $\lambda_k\to 0$.

Thus, $A_k\to A$ in operator norm, and we can conclude that $A$ is compact.

Comment: thanks a lot! But I find it a little bit difficult to understand your proof, I am really new in functional analysis. Could give me a brief proof of the 'facts'? Or could you write down the full proof in more details? That will be a lot of help to me. Thanks soooo much!

Comment: @MartinTien The first fact comes fron the very definition of compact operators and the fact that compact sets in $\mathbb R^k$ are exactly closed and bounded sets. The second fact should be mentioned in all books on functional analysis. For example, take a look at [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator). You should also take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115800/how-to-prove-that-an-operator-is-compact).

Comment: okay! Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: We write $\|(A-A_k)(x)\| \le \sup_{r>k} |\lambda_r|\cdot \|x\|_{\ell_2}$ (it's easy to see why it's true). Can you show why this is true as its not obvious to me?

Comment: @csss $$\|(A-A_k)(x)\| = \sqrt{\sum_{r>k}| \lambda_r x_r|^2}\le \sqrt{\sup_{r>k}|\lambda_r|^2\sum_{r>k}|x_r|^2}=\sup_{r>k}|\lambda_r|\sqrt{|\sum_{r>k}|x_r|^2}$$$$\le\sup_{r>k}|\lambda_r|\sqrt{\sum_{r\ge1}|x_r|^2}=\sup_{r>k} | \lambda_r|\|x\|_{\ell^2}.$$