# $O_P(1) o_P(1) = o_P(1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, weak-convergence

There is something written in the book "Mathematische statistiek" from van der Vaart which I don't see:

"it is short for: if $X_n$ is bounded in probability and $Y_n \rightarrow^P 0$ then $X_nY_n\rightarrow^P 0$. If $X_n$ would also converge in distribution, this would be Slutsky's lemma (with $c=0$). But by Prohorov's theorem $X_n$ converges in distribution 'along subsequences' if it is bounded in probability, so that this rule can still be deduced by arguing 'along subsequences'."

Now some subsequence $X_{n_j}$ converges in distribution and $Y_{n_j}$ converges in probability to $0$, so $X_{n_j}Y_{n_j}$ converges in distrubition to $0$ (Slutsky). I think we cannot conclude that also $X_nY_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution. But van der Vaart thinks differently. Can anyone say what he probably thinks?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3120474/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_n:=X_nY_n$. We can prove that for any subsequence $\left(Z_{n_k}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$, there exists a further subsequence which goes to $0$ in distribution. This proves that $Z_n\to 0$ in distribution. Otherwise, there would exist a positive $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ and $n_j\uparrow \infty$ such that $\mathbb P\left(\left|Z_{n_j}\right|\gt\varepsilon\right)\geqslant\delta$ for all $j$, and extracting a further subsequence yields a contradiction.

Comment: Oh ok. So if we take $n_j$ arbitrarily then we can say $X_{n_j}$ is bounded in probability and $Y_{n_j}\rightarrow ^P 0$. Then the argument I used says that there is a further subsequence s.t. $X_{n_{j_k}}Y_{n_{j_k}}\rightarrow ^d 0$. And with the second sentence you wrote ("We can prove... subsequence ") and which is possible to proof with a simple argument, we can yet conclude that the whole $X_nY_n\rightarrow ^d 0$.

Comment: * which is possible to prove by the argument you used.