# Proof of $O_P(1) o_P(1) = o_P(1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Consider $U_n=O_P(1)$ and $X_n=o_P(1)$. Show that $U_nX_n=o_P(1)$.

Since $o_P(1)$ is equivalent to convergence in probability, it suffices to show that $P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon) \to 0$. However, I am not quite sure if my proof is right:

$$P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon) = P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon, |U_n| \leq M) + P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon, |U_n|>M).$$

For the first term on the right-hand side it holds:

$$P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon, |U_n| \leq M) \leq  P(|U_n| \leq M) < \epsilon.$$

From the definition of $O_P(1)$ we know that for each $\epsilon$ such an $M$ exists.

For the second term, it holds that:

$$P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon, |U_n| > M) \leq P(|MX_n|> \varepsilon) = P\left(|X_n|> \frac \varepsilon  M\right) \to 0.$$

Hence,

$P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon) < \epsilon$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you reversed the $\leq$ and $\gt$: it should be 
$$
P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon, |U_n| \color{red}{\gt} M) \leq  P(|U_n| \color{red}{\gt}  M) < \epsilon
$$
and 
$$P(|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon, |U_n|\color{red}{\leq} M) \leq P(|MX_n|> \varepsilon) = P\left(|X_n|> \frac \varepsilon  M\right) \to 0.$$

Comment: I was looking through this as a worked example of $o_P(\cdot)$ and $O_P(\cdot)$ proofs, but I'm unable to understand to how get the 1st inequality in the 2nd line of your working, that is: $$P(|U_n X_n | > \epsilon, |U_n | \leq M) \leq P(\lvert MX_n \rvert > \epsilon)$$
. I would appreciate if you could briefly clarify?

Comment: @microhaus If $|U_nX_n|>\varepsilon$ and $|U_n| \leq M$, then $$\varepsilon<|U_nX_n|=\lvert U_n\rvert \lvert X_n\rvert\leqslant M\lvert X_n\rvert.$$