# Using Prohorov's theorem to prove uniform tightness

Tags: asymptotics, weak-convergence

I am currently studying van der Vaart's [**Asymptotic statistics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802256). I have a question on the following example in Section 2.2:

> "Prove that $o_{P}(1)O_{P}(1)=o_{P}(1)$"

Let me give some **definitions** first, just in case:

> $X_{n}=o_{P}(1)$ denotes that the sequence of random vectors $X_{n}$
> **converges in probability** to $0$, in other words
> $X_{n}\overset{P}{\to}0$, or $P(\lVert X_{n}\rVert>\varepsilon)\to0$
> for all $\varepsilon>0$.
>
> $Y_{n}=O_{P}(1)$ denotes that the sequence of random vectors $Y_{n}$
> is bounded in probability, which is the same as saying that $Y_{n}$ is
> **uniformly tight** (according to van der Vaart), namely for every
> $\varepsilon>0$ exists constant $M>0$ such that
> $\underset{n}{\text{sup}}\ P(\lVert Y_{n}\rVert>M)<\varepsilon$.
>
> In addition, by $X_{n}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}X$ I denote the **weak convergence**, or **convergence in distribution** of the sequence of random vectors $X_{n}$ to some random vector $X$, namely that $P(X_{n}\le x)\to P(X\le x)$.

Let me also write Prohorov's theorem (Theorem 2.4 in van der Vaart's [**Asymptotic statistics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802256)), as I will be referring to it:

> **Prohorov's theorem** Let $X_{n}$ be random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$.
>
> (i) If $X_{n}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}X$ for some $X$, then
> $\{X_{n}\}$ is uniformly tight;
>
> (ii) If $X_{n}$ is uniformly tight,
> then there exists a subsequence with
> $X_{n_{j}}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}X$ as $j\to\infty$, for some $X$.

I will now illustrate the proof of van der Vaart for $o_{P}(1)O_{P}(1)=o_{P}(1)$.

Suppose $X_{n}=o_{P}(1)$ and $Y_{n}=O_{P}(1)$. Hence, $X_{n}\overset{P}{\to}0$, whereas $Y_{n}$ is uniformly tight.

van der Vaart uses Prohorov's theorem (ii) to argue that there exists a subsequence $\{n_{j}\}$ along which $Y_{n_{j}}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}Y$, for some $Y$, as $j\to\infty$.

The idea of van der Vaart comes from the fact that if $Y_{n_{j}}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}Y$, then we can involve Slutsky's lemma to argue that $X_{n_{j}}Y_{n_{j}}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}0\cdot Y=0$, and then use Prohorov's theorem (i) to show that $\{X_{n_{j}}Y_{n_{j}}\}$ is uniformly tight, thus bounded in probability: $X_{n_{j}}Y_{n_{j}}=O_{P}(1)$.

However, this proof does not seem complete. The proof only holds along this subsequence $\{n_{j}\}$ on which uniform tightness implies weak convergence, but what happens with the reamining terms of the sequence $\{n\}$?

> *van der Vaart, A. W.*, [**Asymptotic statistics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802256), Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics, 3. Cambridge: Cambridge Univ. Press. xv, 443 p. (1998). [ZBL0910.62001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0910.62001)..

Answer (score 1):

Following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2276695/610382) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3827754/610382) I think I got an argument in place.

Set $Z_{n}\doteq X_{n}Y_{n}$ to simplify the notation.

We have shown that any sequence $\{Z_{n}\}$ contains a subsequence $\{Z_{n_j}\}$ that converges weakly to zero, namely $Z_{n_j}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}0$, and, hence, is uniformly tight by Prohorov's theorem (i). Furthermore, we can prove that weak convergence to a constant implies convergence in probability to the constant, namely $Z_{n_j}\overset{P}{\to}0$, see for example Theorem 2.7 in van der Vaart's [**Asymptotic statistics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802256).

Given that $X_{n_j}=o_{P}(1)$ and $Y_{n_j}=O_{P}(1)$ we repeat van der Vaart's logic, Prohorov's theorem (ii) and Slutsky's lemma, to show that any subsequence $\{Z_{n_j}\}$ contains a further subsequence $\{Z_{n_{j_k}}\}$ which converges to weakly to zero.

Suppose now that $\{Z_{n}\}$ does not converge weakly to zero. In this case, there exist $\varepsilon>0$, $\delta>0$, and $\{n_j\}$ such that $P(\lVert Z_{n_j}\rVert>\varepsilon)\ge\delta$ for all $j$. However, $\{Z_{n_j}\}$ contains a further subsequence $\{Z_{n_{j_k}}\}$ that converges weakly to $0$ and consequently converges in probability to $0$. Hence, for all $j\in\{j_{k}\ |\ k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ we have $P(\lVert Z_{n_j}\rVert>\varepsilon)<\delta$. As this is a contradiction, $Z_{n}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}0\implies Z_{n}\overset{P}{\to}0$.

> *van der Vaart, A. W.*, [**Asymptotic statistics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802256), Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics, 3. Cambridge: Cambridge Univ. Press. xv, 443 p. (1998). [ZBL0910.62001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0910.62001).

Answer (score 0):

The sequence indexed by the other {n} will also converge to zero, but that is not a helpful answer. Better is to prove the claim via a contradiction.

Suppose the whole sequence does not converge to zero. Then there is a subsequence that is bounded away from zero. But as you have discovered: this subsequence has further subsequence that does converge to zero. Contradiction.

By the way, a direct proof from the definitions is also possible, and to me more satisfying.